# Where can I find what symbol types are under different symbol kinds in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am trying to RegisterSymbolAction using following code:

```
context.RegisterSymbolAction(AnalyzeSymbol, SymbolKind.???);
```

I have found exact node I want to match using `Syntax Visualizer`:

[image]

You can see that the window says the `Kind` is `Attribute`, but `SymbolKind` enumeration [does not offer](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/SymbolKind.cs) this kind.

As you can see, I am confused – I thought that the syntax tree shows me exactly the syntax nodes symbol actions speak about. But now I am not so sure.

If I am doing basically the right thing, I want to ask: where can I learn what `SymbolKind` enumeration value should I use for given node type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silly mistake: the solution is to use `RegisterSyntaxNodeAction` with `SyntaxKind` enumeration as `SyntaxNode` is what I want to visit.

The problem "What symbol it is?" continues when I am trying to get symbol from semantic model, but now I can look up type in immediate window: it's [`SourceConstructorSymbol`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/IMethodSymbol.cs,4effe2f191a6f60d), so it's [`IMethodSymbol`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/IMethodSymbol.cs,4effe2f191a6f60d).